# How to apply feature selection based on tf-idf threshold

Tags: classification, feature-selection

Let's say we have the following matrix (typical VSM example):

```
         word1    word2    word3    word4
doc1     0.838    0.918    0.001    0.482
doc2     0.311    0.948    0.001    0.183
doc3     0.001    0.928    0.592    0.381
```

I want to initially get rid of some words with a low tf-idf weighting, but I am not sure what to do with words as word1 in my example. word1 is worthless for doc3 but looks important for doc1.

Should I take an average of these weights and put a threshold there?